# React Native How to import JSX file in TSX file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am getting following error. While import the JSX file in TSX File in React Native

**Error**

```
Unable to resolve module ../../components/Chart` from `StatisticalScreen.tsx:**<br>

None of these files exist:<br>
  
 app/components/Chart(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

**Chart.jsx file**

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native"

const Chart = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Your Component</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Chart
```

I had tried to change in the tsConfig file to allowJs:true but not working.

Comment: Any reason you can't change `Cart.jsx` to a `Chart.tsx`?

Comment: I had long third party code. thats difficult to convert code

Comment: primary convert is as simple as renaming jsx to tsx. no need to handle types immedeately, you can do it later. if your webpack does not built if you have errors, you can just add ignore to the fileto skip type check. just dont forget to fix it later